# Open Cart, не совсем понимаю логику обновления и чистки кеша в модификаторах

Tags: opencart, кэширование, view, controller, model

Вообщем как я понимаю у меня имеется catalog из которого контроллеры и вьюхи после выполнения обновления кеша попадают в папку modification/catalog, откуда они и подтягиваются на сайт, но я не совсем понимаю почему у меня добавляются какие-то функции и код к уже имеющемуся коду из основной папки catalog, сделал поиск по файлам, чтобы посмотреть где еще используются эти функции и увидел, что идет вроде как какое то добавление в xml файлах, помогите пожалуйста у меня сейчас башка взорвется:

```
`<add position="before"><![CDATA[
                protected function min_css() {
                    $css_files = array(
                        'view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                        'view/javascript/revolution/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
                        'view/theme/revolution/stylesheet/stylesheet.css',
                        $this->config->get('revtheme_all_settings')['n_progres'] ? 'view/javascript/revolution/nprogress.css' : false,
                        'view/javascript/revolution/jasny-bootstrap.min.css',
                        'view/javascript/revolution/magnific-popup.css',
                        'view/javascript/revolution/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css',
                        $this->config->get('revtheme_all_settings')['mobile_header'] == '2' ? 'view/javascript/revolution/jquery.mmenu.css' : false,
                        'view/theme/revolution/stylesheet/stylesheet_change.css'
                    );
                    $file_min_css = DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/revolution/stylesheet/stylesheet_min.css';
                    if ($css_files && !file_exists($file_min_css)) {
                        $all_css = '';
                        foreach ($css_files as $css_file) {
                            if ($css_file) {
                                $all_css .= file_get_contents(DIR_APPLICATION . $css_file);
                            }
                        }
                        $all_css = str_replace('../fonts/', 'fonts/', $all_css);
                        $all_css = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $all_css);
                        $all_css = str_replace(': ', ':', $all_css);
                        $all_css = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '', $all_css);
                        $all_css = str_replace(array('  ', '    ', '    '), ' ', $all_css);
                        file_put_contents($file_min_css, $all_css);
                    }
                }
                protected function min_js() {
                    $js_files = array(
                        'view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                        'view/javascript/revolution/common.js',
                        'view/javascript/revolution/js_change.js',
                        $this->config->get('revtheme_header_menu')['type'] ? 'view/javascript/revolution/aim.js' : false,
                        $this->config->get('revtheme_header_menu')['type'] ? $this->config->get('revtheme_header_menu')['on_line_cat'] ? 'view/javascript/revolution/amazoncategory_2.js' : 'view/javascript/revolution/amazoncategory.js' : false,
                        $this->config->get('revtheme_header_search')['ajax_search_status'] ? 'view/javascript/revolution/ajax_search.js' : false,
                        $this->config->get('revtheme_all_settings')['all_document_snow_on'] ? 'view/javascript/revolution/snow.min.js' : false,
                        $this->config->get('revtheme_all_settings')['mobile_header'] == '2' ? 'view/javascript/revolution/jquery.mmenu.js' : false
                    );
                    $file_min_js = DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/javascript/revolution/javascript_min.js';
                    if ($js_files) {
                        if (!file_exists($file_min_js)) {
                            $all_js = '';
                            foreach ($js_files as $js_file) {
                                if ($js_file) {
                                    $all_js .= file_get_contents(DIR_APPLICATION . $js_file);
                                    $all_js .= "\r\n\r\n";
                                }
                            }
                            $all_js = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $all_js);
                            $all_js = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $all_js);
                            $all_js = preg_replace('/[^\S\n]+/', ' ', $all_js);
                            $all_js = str_replace(array(" \n", "\n "), "\n", $all_js);
                            $all_js = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", $all_js);
                            $all_js = str_replace(': ', ':', $all_js);
                            $all_js = preg_replace(array('(( )+{)','({( )+)'), '{', $all_js);
                            $all_js = preg_replace(array('(( )+})','(}( )+)','(;( )*})'), '}', $all_js);
                            $all_js = preg_replace(array('(;( )+)','(( )+;)'), ';', $all_js);
                            $all_js = str_replace(array(' {',' }','{ ','; '),array('{','}','{',';'), $all_js);
                            file_put_contents($file_min_js, $all_js);
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]]></add>`
```